# Un-archiving single file hanging

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I am trying to unarchive a very large directory. Here is what works to `untar` the entire thing:

```
$ sudo tar -xjf itunes20140618.tbz --verbose
x itunes20140618/
x itunes20140618/genre_artist
x itunes20140618/imix_type
...etc...
```

However, if I try and un-archive only a single file, it will correctly do so, but then the command will hang indefinitely. In addition, it doesn't print any of the output when using the `--verbose` statement. Here is an example:

```
$ sudo tar -xjf itunes20140618.tbz itunes20140618/imix --verbose
[ nothing prints...it just hangs. But it does un-tar that single file ]
```

Comment: This question is better suited in [unix.SE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tar doesn't have a central table of contents; each file is concatenated, one after the other, so it's continuing to scan the file. It will take about as long to extract one file as it would the whole archive. Per Mark Plotnick's comment below, on GNU tar, you can use `--occurrence=1` to have it stop scanning after it finds your file.

For OS X and other places that have a tar that doesn't support the --occurrence=1 argument, a solution would be a monitoring process that watches for the appearance of the file, and once it remains the same size for a couple of seconds, kills the tar process. Here's a bash function to provide that:

```
untarOneFile () {
    options=$1
    archivename=$2
    filename=$3
    if [[ -f "$archivename" ]]; then
        rm -rf "$filename" 2> /dev/null
        tar "$options" "$archivename" "$filename" &
        pid=$! 
        size=0
        quitCount=0
        oldsize=0
        while true; do
            [[ -f "$filename" ]] && size=$(ls -l "$filename" | cut -c 27- | sed 's/^ *//' | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
            if (( $oldsize > 0 )); then
                if (( $oldsize == $size )); then
                    (( quitCount++ ))
                else
                    quitCount=0
                fi
            fi
            (( $quitCount == 4 )) && break
            oldsize=$size
            sleep 0.5
        done
        kill $pid
    else
        echo "Archive file not found."
    fi
}
```

Error checking is not robust, but if you give it legit info, it works. Usage is:

```
untarOneFile -jxvf tarArchiveFile.tar.bz file/you/want/to/extract
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helps a lot. Is there another tool I can use to extract the archive in a faster way? I usually use python.

Comment: Not really; you have to scan the entire contents for the file to extract; it could be at the start or the end. If you want better performance then you really have to use a better format e.g. zip.

Comment: If you're using GNU tar, try the --occurrence=1 option.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Wow that's really the elegant solution. Thanks. I'm also posting a bulkier solution for non-GNU tar (e.g. on OS X).